# WebApi POST with additional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using WebAPI2 .NET5 to create a controller that Inserts records into our database.

I would like to know if it is possible to pass additional parameters to the HttpPOST method ?
I specifically want to pass a boolean value along with the payload object to manipulate the way in which the object is persisted in the database (we have two different databases, one for training and the other for production)

MSDN defines the POST method signature something like as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Pet> Create([FromBody]Pet pet)
{
    .....
}
```

Towards this end I have tried creating an endpoint with the following signature:

```
[HttpPost("CreatePet/{training:bool}")]
public ActionResult<Pet> Create(bool training, [FromBody]Pet pet)
{
    // do some if(training) logic here...
    .....
}
```

My thought here is that the request URL will become

```
baseAddress + "/CreatePet/{training}"
e.g.
http://localhost:500/api/CreatePet/true
```

Now, using the HttpClient's PostAsync method to call an endpoint as above produces a 404 not found error.

Is there a solution to this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your action header:

```
[Route("~/api/CreatePet/{training:bool}")]
public ActionResult<Pet> Create(bool training, [FromBody]Pet pet)
{
    // do some if(training) logic here...
    .....
}
```